# Xcode ignores some of my lines

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a part in my code that calls a method on a different class.

**The different class is a singleton.**

I didn't have any issues with this `class` until `today`, everything worked properly. I don't know why, but after a few insignificant changes i've made `today`, the code seems to ignore some of my code. It seems that everything is ok and it passes through all the lines but if i put a breakpoint inside one of the methods in my singleton class, it doesn't stop. It just doesn't call those methods.

**Does anyone has an idea why could that be?**

I tried cleaning the project, tried quitting `Xcode`, nothing helped so far.

This is an example of how my method in my singleton ".m" looks like:

```
-(void)setUserCurrentLocationWithLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude andLongitude:(NSNumber *)longitude andUserIndex:(NSNumber *)userIndex{
    NSMutableArray* tempPlayersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey: @"kgpsUsersArray"]];

    NSMutableDictionary * userTempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[tempPlayersArray objectAtIndex:[userIndex integerValue]]];

    NSLog(@"latitude = %f",[latitude floatValue]);

    [userTempDict setObject:latitude forKey:@"latitude"];
    [userTempDict setObject:longitude forKey:@"longitude"];

    [defaults setObject:tempPlayersArray forKey:@"kgpsUsersArray"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And this is how it is defined in ".h" file:

```
-(void)setUserCurrentLocationWithLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitude andLongitude:(NSNumber *)longitude andUserIndex:(NSNumber *)userIndex;
```

And in my viewController.m file the singleton is being called initialized like this:

```
#import "PlayersData.h"
usersData = [PlayersData sharedInstance];
```

and the method is called like this:

```
[usersData setUserCurrentLocationWithLatitude:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:32.125493] andLongitude:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:34.858962] andUserIndex:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hmmmm... I am trying to divine what your project looks like or what your code looks like...  but my crystal ball has such fuzzy reception.  Maybe you should post some code that shows how you're defining your singleton and/or how you are trying to call it?

Comment: I am trying to deduce what this has to do with Xcode. Also, I'm sure that those insignificant changes aren't that insignificant... Consider `if (n == 0) return 0;` vs `if (n = 0) return 0;` vs. `if (n == 0); return 0;`...

Comment: If you're using a version control system (like SVN or git), use it to see what you've changed recently.  If you're not using a version control system, but you have Time Machine enabled, use it to see what you've changed recently.  If you aren't using a version control system and you aren't using Time Machine, now you know why you should be using both.  Put a breakpoint in the code that calls into your non-called code, and then single step to see what it's doing instead of calling your non-called code.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the `[usersData setUserCurrentLocationWithLatitude:...]` line?  Did you make sure that line is reached?  Did you try printing `usersData` in the debugger?  Are you sure it's not nil?

Comment: BINGO! Thanks man, it was nil… I have no Idea how it changed. I guess shit happens, thanks again!

Comment: Would you like to publish a formal answer? I'll make sure to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the singelton was not created. Debug it, to be sure it is not nil.